# In Digimon World, Punimon said "buy item after digivolving, something good will happen", what is it?

Tags: digimon-world

Digimon World for PlayStation (PSOne). At some point Punimon will explain that you can press Start at shops to see item description, and say "buy an item after digivolving, something good will happen".

What is this "something good" and how do I trigger it?

Answer (score 3):

You may (but not necessarly always) get a discount on your purchase

Comment: How long does it last? Is it "the first time you shop after digivolution" or "for a certain length of time after digivolution"?

Comment: I can't answer that. I've only experienced the discount because I actually managed to digivolve after healing in the clinic.

Comment: @Raestloz Although it's worth noting that in Digimon World events seem to be based around Quarter Clocks (Several Digimon Encounters can only happen in 1 of Quarter of the day).  It's quite possible that you can only get the discount if you visit the shop in the same quarter you digivolved in. But this is just an educated guess, not a fact

Comment: Did the store clerk say anything that informs you of the discount or was everything just fine but the price suddenly dropped?

Comment: You get a warning. But I'm not sure if you get it only the first time it happens of if it warns you whenever you have a newly digivolved digimon. Although I'm not sure if the discount is applied before or after you buy